# ASP.NET Core cannot find cshtml file by path using RazorViewEngine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to find my `cshtml` file in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API project. To do it, I'm using this code:

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = this.serviceProvider };
var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

var viewResult = this.razorViewEngine.FindView(
                actionContext,
                "~/PdfTemplate/ProjectRaport.cshtml",
                false);
```

The file is here:

[image]

But from code above, the `View` (that is `~/PdfTemplate/ProjectRaport.cshtml`) is null.

How to find specific file by path in `WebApi Core`?

This code works ok:

```
var viewResult = this.razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext,
                Path.Combine(this.hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "PdfTemplate", "ProjectRaport.cshtml"),
                false);
```

Path to file is ok, but the `View` in `viewResult` is still null

When I tried `GetView`:

```
var viewResult = this.razorViewEngine.GetView(
                Path.Combine(this.hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "PdfTemplate", "ProjectRaport.cshtml"),
                Path.Combine(this.hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "PdfTemplate", "ProjectRaport.cshtml"),
                false);
```

the `viewResult.View` is still null

**EDIT**

In `SearchedLocations` the path is ok:

[image]

[image]

When I deleted `.cshtml` extension, `SearchedLocations` is empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor engine cant find view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996438/razor-engine-cant-find-view)

Comment: This is `WebApi` project not `MVC`

Comment: Did you try without the .cshtml extension?

Comment: @hugo yes, same story

Comment: @hugo check my edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently tried to implement the razor  email template explained by Scott Sauber

Tutorial here: https://scottsauber.com/2018/07/07/walkthrough-creating-an-html-email-template-with-razor-and-razor-class-libraries-and-rendering-it-from-a-net-standard-class-library/

Issue was that I had  to overcome a bug(https://stackoverflow.com/a/56504181/249895) that needed the relative netcodeapp2.2 that the asemblied resided in.

```
var viewPath = ‘~/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Views/MainView.cshtml’;

_viewEngine.GetView(executingFilePath: viewPath , viewPath: viewPath , isMainPage: true);
```

Getting the `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2` can be achieved by using this code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
public class RenderingService : IRenderingService
{

    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public RenderingService(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public string RelativeAssemblyDirectory()
    {
        var contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
        string executingAssemblyDirectoryAbsolutePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string executingAssemblyDirectoryRelativePath = System.IO.Path.GetRelativePath(contentRootPath, executingAssemblyDirectoryAbsolutePath);
        return executingAssemblyDirectoryRelativePath;
    }
}
```

All fine and dandy until I had issues regarding the template file. Problem was that even though the file is in `~\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2` it searches for the template in the root folder such as `rootfolder\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` and not in `rootfolder\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`.

This is most likely generated by the fact that I have the views as an embedded resource in a `CLASS LIBRARY` and not in a Web Api solution directly.
[image: class library]
[image: folder structure]

The weird part is that if you do not have the files in the root folder, you still get the `CACHED` Layout page.

The good part is that when you PUBLISH the solution, it flattens the solution so the `VIEWS` are in `ROOT` folder.

[image: publish]

[Solution]

The solution seems to be in the Startup.cs folder.

Got my solution from here: [Cannot find view located in referenced project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50934768/249895)

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/q/50934768/249895
services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions>(o => {
                o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/{0}" + Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
                o.FileProviders.Add(new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(AppContext.BaseDirectory));
            });
```

After this, you can put your code like this:

```
var contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
string executingAssemblyDirectoryAbsolutePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string executingAssemblyDirectoryRelativePath = System.IO.Path.GetRelativePath(contentRootPath, executingAssemblyDirectoryAbsolutePath);

string executingFilePath = $"{executingAssemblyDirectoryAbsolutePath.Replace('\\', '/')}/Views/Main.cshtml";
string viewPath = "~/Views/Main.cshtml";
string mainViewRelativePath = $"~/{executingAssemblyDirectoryRelativePath.Replace('\\','/')}/Views/Main.cshtml";

var getViewResult = _viewEngine.GetView(executingFilePath: executingFilePath, viewPath: viewPath, isMainPage: true);

<!-- OR -->

var getViewResult = _viewEngine.GetView(executingFilePath: viewPath, viewPath: viewPath, isMainPage: true);
```

Comment: Info also here: http://justcodesnippets.durlut.ro/index.php/2019/11/01/issue-of-razorviewengine-caching-and-layout-location-in-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a working response to my question, so I posted my solution that works.

Instead of using `PathCombine` with `ContentRootPath`, just type :

```
string viewPath = "~/PdfTemplate/ProjectRaport.cshtml";
var viewResult = this.razorViewEngine.GetView(viewPath, viewPath, false);
```

and it works ok

Comment: Just to add to your comment, you might also have some caching issues. Your solution worked, but only after I copied the Views folder with all its content to these folders: bin\Debug\ and bin\ . After you delete the folders from there, it keeps working. Pretty stupid.

Comment: Amazing stuff! Please post it as answer so another will find it easier

Comment: Still have to fix the caching issues. Apparently if I change the layout from red to green it still displays the red one.

Comment: I've added my findings